# How to add extension to route ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to know if there is a way to add an extension to the end or a URI in ASP.NET. Normally, the RouteConfig is configured like this: `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"`, so, the result would be like this: `http://example.com/Home/TestPage/1`, but I would like to add an extension to the end of the URI (just for fun, and just to know it), like this `http://example.com/Home/TestPage/1.extension`, it this possible to do? And how can I do it?

Comment: Do you want different extensions? Or just add like .html to every URL?

Comment: @Wiizl yes, add something like .html to every URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression constraint with the parameter, `{id:^.*\.(extension1|extension2)$}`